# Validation on save in arcobject

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3

I want to validate all the features that have been changed since last save. Currently I'm trying to do this in an `ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension`. My sde database is not versioned.

```c#
public class EditorExtension : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension
{

    void editEventsEvent2_BeforeStopEditing(bool save)
    {
        var iEditor = ArcGisSingletons.GetIEditor();

        if (iEditor.HasEdits())
        {
            var enumDatasetName = iEditor.EditSelection;
            enumDatasetName.Reset();
            var datasetName = enumDatasetName.Next();
            while (datasetName != null)
            {
                var snid = datasetName.HasSnid() ? datasetName.Snid() : -1;
                Trace.TraceInformation("dataset Name: " + datasetName.Class.AliasName + ", Type: " +
                                       datasetName.FeatureType +
                                       ", Category: " + snid.ToString());
                datasetName = enumDatasetName.Next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying with the `EditSelection` but I really just want a reference to all editing objects in order to run through them and check if they are valid.

How can I get a reference all the objects that have been changed since last save?

Is there another way to validate the edited objects in arcobjects?

Comment: Have a look at IWorkspaceEdit2.EditDataChanges (using esriEditDataChangesType.esriEditDataChangesWithinSession), this should give you a list of the IDs of the features that have been modified since last save. I have not tested this so can't put this as an answer but it sounds like what you're after.